# Excel Formula to split columns where cells may contain multiple values into another column, where each cell only contains a single value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, powerquery

I have a column in Excel that looks like the below:

[image: Sample]

And what I want is a formula that can copy the column into the next column splitting each cell with multiple values so that each cell will only contain a single value. Similar to this:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Powerquery, Split by linefeed and into new rows =)

Let's imagine this set of data:

[image]

- Select your data, `A1:A7` in this example.
- Import this data into PowerQuery AKA Get&Transform (including headers).
- Under "Home" click, "Split Column" and choose "By Delimiter".
- Use a custom delimiter: `#(lf)` and under advanced tick "Rows".
- Hit "OK" and close PQ. Your results are there.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I upvoted. But it took me a while to translate "Import this data into PowerQuery AKA Get&Transform (including headers)." to "Data tab > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range" and even then I probably took a bite from the wrong end of the sausage because I never found the "Start" button. But I did find "Split Column" (Office 365) and it was plain sailing after that.

Comment: @Variatus, it's sometimes a guessing game for me since my Office is in Dutch. In PQ there should be a "Start" tab, where splitting is a button. Does that reflect on your end?

Comment: In English it is the `Home` ribbon / `Transform` tab. (And it is also on the `Transform` ribbon / `Text Column` tab)

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld I don't have a `Transform` tab on the `Home` ribbon, nor can such a tab be added in Options > Customize ribbon.

Comment: @JvdV Not only for you. There seem to be major differences between versions even in English. I suspect that I found PQ itself only by a backdoor or side entrance. Hence no `Start` button. Mine is Office 365, US English platform.