# Excel Column to Rows with it's Other Data

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet that looks like this:

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME COURSE
John      Doe      1,2
Jane      Doe      1,3
```

Does Excel have any functionality to end up with something like this:

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME COURSE
John      Doe      1
John      Doe      2
Jane      Doe      1
Jane      Doe      3
```

I've seen some samples on `Text to Columns` but that doesn't seem like what I want. Is there a combination of `magical` formulas to create such results?

I'm perfectly fine with this result as well (I'm currently trying `LOOKUP`, `VLOOKUP`, and/or `HLOOKUP` for this):

SHEET1

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME COURSE
John      Doe      1
Jane      Doe      1
```

SHEET2

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME COURSE
John      Doe      2
```

SHEET3

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME COURSE
Jane      Doe      3
```

Thank you.

Comment: Probably using Power Query.

Comment: Powerquery indead got a function to split rows into rows...

Comment: Interesting! Never knew abut this. I'm researching it now, can you provide sample steps to take while I do more research? Thank you.

Comment: @rolyrolls, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64313519/9758194) is an example. You can do the same thing with multiple columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the data into Power Query. Then use ribbon commands to

- Split the Course column by the comma delimiter
- select the two name columns
- Transform > Unpivot Other Columns
- rename the columns for Attribute and Value
- remove columns you don't need
- load into Excel

Comment: This is beautiful! Question: Why "Unpivot Other Columns"?

Comment: Don't overthink it, this is way to complicated. You can just split into rows directly

Comment: @JvdV If I understand what you mean: only do step #1? Since I actually did have more data columns I actually removed them first then did the `Split Columns` into rows and it worked. I am, though, curious as to @teylyn's solution for the `Transform > Unpivot Other Columns`.

Comment: All you need to do is load your data into PQ. Then select the third column, use the split column function. Under that function it says "advanced options", tick the "rows" box instead of columns. That's all @RoLYroLLs.

Comment: @JvdV yes I did that works like a charm. but what's the `Transform > Unpivot Other Columns` for is what I'm asking (I did not do that part and don't need to). Inquiring minds want to know. =)

Comment: @RoLYroLLs, discard all those steps as what Teylyn showed here (tell me if I'm wrong) is a split into columns first instead of rows. Then the whole *unpivot* thing is needed to remove all created columns and get these courses into seperate rows.

Comment: oh! got it! Then I guess I didn't do what @teylyn did. I used `Split Columns` and selected Rows in the advanced menu (found it as I'm always curious and I tend to look around more). I guess that's why I didn't understand what you were saying at first. Thanks again!